# Utilizing a DLL not in System32

Tags: c, windows, dll, compilation, admin

I am running on a system which I don't have administrative access on

An exe I am trying to run utilizes msvcp140.dll, and currently upon running will not run and throw an error message specifying that msvpc140.dll is missing.

Normally I would just install the dll to system32 and be done with it, however in this case I do not have administrative privileges.

Is there a way to map to this dll when running it? Some sort of batch command? Would this have to be somehow linked when compiling? Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the DLL is not in the system's search path. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) for details. But the *correct* way to get the DLL is to install the "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package"
instead.

Answer (score 1):

you have the following options:

1. add the .dll to the directory where your .exe is located.  This particular .dll is redistributable, meaning you can include it with your installer, although the proper way is to invoke MS VC++ redistributable installer.
2. recompile your application to use static linking to C++ runtime.  In this case you won't need the .dll at all

Comment: is there more to the first step? Having the .dll in the same folder as the .exe is not working :(

Comment: nevermind, that worked.. but now I am getting "application unable to start correctly..."

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should copy `msvcp140.dll` into the system folder in case. System32 is a global folder, so any change of dlls in this directory can affect all installed applications.

This article from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-to-an-application-local-folder?view=vs-2019):

> Describes how to deploy a Visual C++ application by copying files to
> its folder.
>
> Copy the appropriate MFC and C Run-Time (CRT) library files from the Visual Studio installation directory in the \VC\redist\version folder, and then paste them in the \Release\ folder of your MFC project.

This is also relevant for non MFC applications deployment.